# Java Spring Boot: Swagger GET List in the Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am trying to setup a GET request in Java Spring Boot Swagger, with a list of ProductIds in the request. How can I edit the code below for this?

```
@GET
@Path("/product/{customerId}/{productIds}")
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Get Products",
        response = ProductResponse.class,
        responseContainer = "List"
)
List<ProductResponse> getProductData(
        @ApiParam(value = "customerId", required = true) @PathParam("customerId") long customerId,
        @ApiParam(value = "productIds", required = true) @PathParam("productIds") List<Long> productIds
);
```

Result: with CustomerId 7 and ProductIds (2,3)

```
404 Not Found

http://localhost:50111/product-domain/api/product/7/2%2C3
```

Update: if I use RequestParam for ProductIds, how would I input this in swagger body? Note: any solution will work, (don't necessarily need to use RequestParam)

```
   @RequestParam(value="productIds", required=true) List<Long> productIds
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should not use PathVariable but RequestParam (preferably RequestBody) in this case.

In case of using RequestParam it is should looks like:

```
@Path("/product/{customerId}")
List<ProductResponse> getProductData(
        @ApiParam(value = "customerId", required = true) @PathParam("customerId") long customerId,
        @ApiParam(value = "productIds", required = true) @RequestParam("productIds") List<Long> productIds
);
```

than your url will look like: http://localhost:50111/product-domain/api/product/7?productIds=2,3

In case of using RequestBody it is should looks like:

```
@Path("/product/{customerId}")
List<ProductResponse> getProductData(
        @ApiParam(value = "customerId", required = true) @PathParam("customerId") long customerId,
        @ApiParam(value = "productIds", required = true) @RequestBody("productIds") List<Long> productIds
);
```

than your url will look like: http://localhost:50111/product-domain/api/product/7
and your http request body should contains: [2, 3]

Why I advise against using @PathParam in this case?

- Url length has length limit (around 2048 characters) - so if You try pass long list in future it is can be a problem
- Url needs to "normalize"/"escape" special characters, what makes url less readable for human, which is the essence of using PathParam

BTW:
Consider using PathVariable instead of PathParam - because PathVariable is from Spring, but PathParam is from JAX-RS and I assume you want to use Spring Boot

Comment: how do I input in the swagger body, picture above?

Comment: In case when You are declare productIds as RequestParam swagger should not detect this as RequestBody param - it is looks like configuration problem or bug - can You paste entire Controller code?

Comment: But if You decide to use RequestBody - than your swagger body should contains:
[2,3]

Comment: the request body can only be used with POST

Comment: With PUT, PATCH too and "theoretically" with every http method except TRACE - but yes RequestBody is not supported for GET method in this framework. But You can change "GET" to Spring annotation "PostMapping" - if You want to use RequestBody solution.